# Process code parameter in AWS Cognito Hosted UI callback

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

When I use an aws hosted UI I successfully authenticate and am returned to my application:

http://localhost:5173/login-callback?code=92129aae-fe38-4f16-a084-809072a7e8bc

The problem is I can't find any examples of how to process that code parameter.

I'm using Javascript (typescript actually) and the aws-amplify Auth object

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const queryString = window.location.search;` to get the parameter.

For more details, please check this link: [Get URL parameter with javascript](https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/)